# ¿Se puede hacer una consulta en larvael donde se cumplan las dos condiciones where para que realice la consulta?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Necesito hacer una consulta donde se cumplan ambos where, en este caso que mientras sea el usuario X y el status sea PUBLISHED ó DRAFT lo muestre, actualmente tengo:

```
$properties = Accommodation::where("user_id", $id)                         
                            ->where("status", 'PUBLISHED')                 
                            ->orWhere("status", 'DRAFT')                   
                            ->get();
```

El problema es que me los muestra todos, no filtra por usuarios.

Algo como:

```
$properties = Accommodation::where("user_id", $id)AND                      
                           ->where("status", 'PUBLISHED')               
                          AND->orWhere("status", 'DRAFT')                  
                          ->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente no veo para qué complicar la consulta con un closure cuando lo resuelve un simple whereIn, como en SQL «normal»:

```
$properties = Accommodation::whereUserId($id)                         
                    >whereIn('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT'])                
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Gracias, lo había resuelto así porque ví algo en la documentación, tu código está mejor... :) $properties = Accommodation::where([
      ['user_id', '=', $id, 'and', 'status', '=', 'PUBLISHED', 'or', 'DRAFT']
  ])->get();

Comment: sí lo hago como lo publicas o de esta manera, ninguna de las dos compromete el rendimiento o la seguiridad de la aplicación? $properties = Accommodation::where('user_id', $id)                         
            ->whereIn('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT'])                
            ->get();

Comment: No veo por qué se vería comprometida la seguridad, deberías revisar un poco más cómo funciona Laravel internamente, y en cuanto a rendimiento, eso lo puedes probar fácilmente.

Comment: Gracias, realmente no estaba seguro por eso te pregunté... Revisaré aunque estoy diariamente dedicando tiempo y aprendiendo cada día más. Gracias!

Comment: Será que podrías echarle un vistazo a esto? Gracias!!  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225263/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mostrar-las-ciudades-correspondientes-a-la-misma-provincia-en-el-mis

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estas agrupando correctamente tus condiciones en la consulta. Lo puedes solucionar utilizando [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) y haciendo la agrupación de parámetros. Tu código debería quedar algo así:

```
DB::table('accommodation') // <- Nombre de tu tabla.
            ->where('user_id', '=', $id) // <- tu condición 'general'
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', '=', 'PUBLISHED')//<- agrupamiento de condiciones
                      ->orWhere('status', '=', 'DRAFT');
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Manteniendo el uso del modelo `Accomodation`, puedes pasar como segundo argumento del primer `where` una función anónima donde incluyas tanto el `where` y el `orWhere` de este modo

```
$properties = Accommodation::where("user_id", $id)                         
                           ->where(funtion($query){
                               $query->where("status", 'PUBLISHED')
                                     ->orWhere("status", 'DRAFT');
                           })->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que debes hacer es quitar los AND, quedaría algo como esto:

```
$properties = Accommodation::where("user_id", $id)                      
    ->where("status", 'PUBLISHED')               
    ->orWhere("status", 'DRAFT')                  
    ->get();
```

Comment: Gracias, el tema es que de esa manera no me filtra por usuario, me los muestra todos.