# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar las ciudades correspondientes a la misma provincia en el mismo cuadro?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

No sé si está bien como lo estoy haciendo o haya otra mejor manera de solventar lo que necesito, Tengo esto en mi controlador:

```
public function destinations()
{

$accommodations = Accommodation::join('cities', 'accommodations.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
                ->join('provinces','cities.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
                ->join('regions','cities.region_id', '=', 'regions.id')
                ->selectRaw('count(provinces.province) as total_province, provinces.province as province, cities.city as city, count(cities.city) as total_city, regions.region as region')
                ->groupBy('province', 'city', 'region')
                ->get();

return view('web/travelers/destinations', compact('accommodations'));
}
```

Luego muestro esto en mi vista:

```
<div class="row px-5">

        @php $currentProvince = '' @endphp
        @php $currentRegion = '' @endphp
        @php $currentProvinceForCity = '' @endphp
        @foreach($accommodations as $accommodation)
            @php
                $province = str_slug($accommodation->province, '-');
                $region = str_slug($accommodation->region, '-');
                $city = str_slug($accommodation->city, '-');
            @endphp
                @if($accommodation->region != $currentRegion)
                {{ $accommodation->region }}
                @php $currentRegion = $accommodation->region @endphp
                @endif
                <div class="card m-2">  
                    <div class="card-header">
                    @if($accommodation->province != $currentProvince)
                        {{ $accommodation->province }}
                    @php $currentProvince = $accommodation->province @endphp
                    @endif  
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="/alquiler-temporario/{{ $region }}/{{ $province }}/{{ $city }}"> {{ $accommodation->city }} ({{ $accommodation->total_city }})</a>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
        @endforeach
</div>
```

El problema es que no logro insertar en el cuadro las ciudades que corresponden a la misma provincia, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

San Isidro y Miramar deberían estar juntas dentro del mismo cuadro, en este caso provincia de Buenos Aires.

estoy imprimiento todos los registros y los divido con la vista, no tengo como hacer un condicional que sea: Mientras el campo "province_id" sea igual a "x" me imprima con un "for" todas las ciudades de esa provincia... Quizás haya otra mejor solución.

Acá está la relación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que devuelve ($accommodations);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Las provincias y las regiones no tienen ninguna relación? En otras palabras, ¿las provincias pertenecen a regiones o viceversa?

Comment: En este orden, Las Regiones contienen Provincias y las Provincias contienen Ciudades, quiero mostrar Las regiones, con sus provincias y las ciudades de dichas provincias, clasificadas. PD: Las regiones pueden estar conformadas por varias provincias.

Comment: En la imagen de ejemplo se muestra la región de Buenos Aires que contiene la provincia de Buenos Aires y esta contiene dos ciudades... Miramar y San Isidro, el proble está en que me genera un cuaro por cada ciudad, ambas deberían estar en el mismo cuadro (Dentro de la provincia de Buenos Aires). Claro luego al seguir agregando ciudades cada una debería estar contenida dentro del cuadro de su provincia correspondiente.

Comment: En mi vista agregué unas condiciones para que me unan las provincias y no se repita, fue una sugerencia de alguién pero quizás con otro tipo de consulta se pueda solucionar ambas, No repetir Provncias ni Ciudades. O con condicionales en la vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta respuesta voy a explicar con más detalle una propuesta de rediseño, aprovechando las ventajas de Laravel:

1. Definir las relaciones entre los modelos (y en la base de datos):

   Teniendo en cuenta que en los comentarios se especifica que una región contiene varias provincias, debería existir una relación entre dichas tablas en la base de datos y desaparecería el enlace entre ciudades y regiones.

   Las relaciones en los modelos quedarían así:

   Accomodation.php

   ```
   class Accomodation extends Model
   {
       // ...        

       public function city()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   City.php

   ```
   class City extends Model
   {
       // ...        

       public function accomodations()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(Accomodation::class);
       }

       public function province()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   Province.php

   ```
   class Province extends Model
   {
       // ...        

       public function citys()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(City::class);
       }

       public function region()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   Region.php

   ```
   class Region extends Model
   {
       // ...        

       public function provinces()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(Province::class);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Replantear la consulta de Eloquent para aprovechar las relaciones y utilizando algo de Eager Loading:

   ```
   $regions = Region::with('provinces.citys.accomodations')->get();
   ```

   Podría realizarse una mejor consulta incluso, para no cargar las acomodaciones como tal, pero puede ser un poco más engorroso de explicar.
3. Reorganizar la plantilla blade, especialmente para quitar la lógica que no debería estar en dicha capa:

   ```
   @foreach($regions as $region)
     {{ $region->region }}

     @foreach($region->provinces as $province)
     <div class="card m-2">  
       <div class="card-header">
         {{ $province->province }} 
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">

         @foreach($province->citys as $city)
         <a href="/alquiler-temporario/{{ str_slug($region->region) }}/{{ str_slug($province->province }}/{{ str_slug($city->city) }}"> {{ $city->city }} ({{ $city->accomodations->count() }})</a>
         @endforeach

       </div>
     </div>
     @endforeach
   @endforeach
   ```

Por último, cabe resaltar que no he probado este código, por lo cual probablemente existan errores menores, pero el objetivo de esta respuesta es transmitir una nueva idea de solución aprovechando las herramientas de Laravel.

Comment: Buenos días, apenas me levanto... Tengo las relaciones voy a intentar con tu consulta with, me parece que era lo que faltaba para mejorar la alternativa de Marco... Quizás no la viste, el me dío una suguerencia en otra respuesta. Ya voy a intentar. Gracias!

Comment: La forma como está planteada esa respuesta tiene varios errores.

Comment: Hay un pequeño problemita, las tablas Regions y Provinces no están relacionadas en la BD, me da el siguiente error: Call to undefined relationship [provinces] on model [App\Region], si uso City en vez de Region $regions = City::with('provinces.regions.accomodations')->get(); me mustra el siguinte error: QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'provinces.city_id'

Comment: Eso lo expliqué en el punto 1 de la respuesta

Comment: Claro, disculpa... Sólo que asumí que habías visto la captura de la relación en la BD que publiqué en la pregunta. Voy a ver como puedo resolver eso, muchas gracias... El diseño está genial, me da la idea de como funciona, solo ahora debo analizar como adaptarlo a mi relación, o en última instancia rediseñar las relaciones en la BD... Espero que no porque debería luego cambiar otras cosas que dependen de ella.

Comment: Perfecto, lo haré. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Se pueden unir dos with como: Region::with() y Province:with() en una misma consulta?

Comment: Ya se muestran bien, modifiqué la BD, lo que hice fue cambiar el campo region_id de la tabla cities y la coloqué en la tabla provinces... Claro me muestra todas las regiones, provincias y ciudades, ahora necesito mostrar solos las que tienen registros en la tabla accommodations, no veo como incluirlo en la consulta

Comment: Revisa esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo reviso. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión se requiere un rediseño de la parte del sistema que vemos, posteriormente espero poder publicar una propuesta de rediseño, es algo sencillo pero requiere tiempo la explicación.

---

La solución sencilla (pero no la mejor) para que las ciudades queden en el mismo contenedor es utilizar la misma lógica para imprimir la provincia y el contenedor (teniendo en cuenta que la provincia es la que determina la agrupación):

```
<div class="row px-5">

    @php $currentProvince = '' @endphp
    @php $currentRegion = '' @endphp
    @php $currentProvinceForCity = '' @endphp
    @foreach($accommodations as $accommodation)
        @php
            $province = str_slug($accommodation->province, '-');
            $region = str_slug($accommodation->region, '-');
            $city = str_slug($accommodation->city, '-');
        @endphp
            @if($accommodation->region != $currentRegion)
            {{ $accommodation->region }}
            @php $currentRegion = $accommodation->region @endphp
            @endif

            @if($accommodation->province != $currentProvince)
              <div class="card m-2">  
                <div class="card-header">
                  {{ $accommodation->province }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
            @endif  
                  <a href="/alquiler-temporario/{{ $region }}/{{ $province }}/{{ $city }}"> {{ $accommodation->city }} ({{ $accommodation->total_city }})</a>&nbsp;
            @if($accommodation->province != $currentProvince)
                </div>
              </div>
            @endif
            @php $currentProvince = $accommodation->province @endphp
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Chévere, estoy probando, aunque me quedó todo dentro de un mismo cuadro, ya estoy buscando de resolver, pero dentro de provincia quedaron las dos ciudades.

Comment: Sí, cuadro dentro de cuadro... todos dentro de uno principal... Estoy tratando de resolver pero no he podido

Comment: Listo, la agregué al final de la pregunta

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Comment: Ya realicé el cambio, era simplemente mover la línea donde se define la provincia actual a un lugar posterior a las dos comprobaciones.

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizaría la función de hasmany de laravel donde me puede traer todos los datos de un registro relacional, aqui le dejo un ejemplo como guiar
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxzbmz7aiuxl8ph/laravel.png?dl=0
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

inicia por región

```
consulta = regions::witch('cities_all','cities_all.accommodation_all')->get();
```

en el modelo de regions tiene que colocar la siguiente función

```
public funcion cities_all(){
   return $this->Hasmany('App/cities','region_id');
}
```

en el modelo de cities tiene que colocar la siguiente función

```
public funcion accommodation_all(){
   return $this->Hasmany('App/accommodations','city_id');
}
```

en la cual me va a mostrar las regiones y todos las ciudades que tiene esa región

si quiere contar la cantidades de ciudades que tiene un array utilice la función php `var_dump(count($b));` que me permite contar el números de datos de un array

es algo complejo como se ver, pero facilita mucho traer varios datos relacionales

Comment: Hola, voy a probarlo y te aviso, gracias!

Comment: Funciona bien, pero no logro incluir las provincias, cómo podría hacerlo? ví en la documentación esto " return $this->hasManyThrough" pero no me funciona, creo que es para agregar otras tablas